When using ClickHouse, sometimes the number of zk-nodes suddenly increases significantly
When using ClickHouse, if there is a sudden surge of traffic, the bulk write QPS will also increase, and in this case, an increase in the number of zk-nodes is considered normal.
But sometimes the number of zk-nodes suddenly increases significantly even when the bulk write QPS remains unchanged. Has anyone encountered this situation?
I need a reasonable explanation!

Could you please quantify what "significantly" means? More znodes typically mean more memory is required. Are you seeing Keeper going OOM?
